# iOS iphone6 plus crash:[NSConcreteMapTable numberOfSectionsInTableView:]

Tags: ios

I am Crash with iphone6 plus 8.1.3.
the log:
-[NSConcreteMapTable numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f8c3750 
translating『 0x100181f18 』=> main Supporting Files/main.m: line 12
I have no idea why crash.can somebody help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your UITableView object is sending selector (numberOfSectionsInTableView:) of UITableViewDataSourceDelegate to NSConcreteMapTable.
NSConcreteMapTable didn't implement this method.

Comment: I dont understander how UITableView send a selector to NSConcreteMapTable?How can I solve this probrom ? I google this NSConcreteMapTable, no idea what it is.

Comment: Did you setup datasource of your UITableView?

Comment: I dont know which tableview crash. I use thirdpart crash log system.Just get this crash log, so I cant debug.

Comment: Can you post crashed stack? Do you have steps to reproduce?